jetpack compose does not reorganize after change mutableStateOf
I am learning Jetpack Compose. My understanding is that when I change the value of mutableStateOf, the corresponding Composable should recompose. However, in my demo, the Text still displays ‘hello’.
@Preview
@Composable
fun Hello() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("hello") }
    Column {
        Text(text = text)
        text = "world"
    }
}

